# cannot connect to local Cassandra instance?

Tags: cassandra

I am a Cassandra newbie so this is a very rudimentary question. For my project I need an older version of Cassandra, so I installed it like so:

```
brew install python
brew install homebrew/versions/cassandra22
pip install cql
```

After that, I simply started it via Homebrew too, like so:

```
brew services start homebrew/versions/cassandra22
```

I can see it in the list of services having been started:

```
tracyxia$ brew services list
Name        Status  User     Plist
cassandra22 started tracyxia  /Users/tracyxia/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.cassandra22.plist
```

Furthermore, I can also see it running as a service on my Mac:

```
tracyxia$ ps -ef | grep cassandra
1425523232  9962 87919   0  4:33PM ttys000    0:00.00 grep cassandra
```

But when I try to connect to my local instance of Cassandra via DevCenter, I kept getting the "cannot connect to host" error. :( I am pretty sure this is an installation issue because it works perfectly fine when I installed Cassandra 3.0.7 (current default version for Homebrew cassandra).

Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[configure](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml_r.html) listen_address and rpc_address as below in cassandra.yaml

listen_address : 192.168.1.15 (configure local IP)

rpc_address : 0.0.0.0

Comment: Thank you Iam! You were right: it was a problem with the YAML file. "brew uninstall" left the cassandra.yaml file, with configurations for 3.0.7! I saw the following error messages in the system.log file: 

    ERROR [main] 2016-08-02 16:55:37,550 CassandraDaemon.java:638 -  Exception encountered during startup
org.apache.cassandra.exceptions.ConfigurationException: Invalid yaml. Please remove properties [credentials_validity_in_ms...] from your cassandra.yaml

After manually wiping Cassandra everywhere, reinstalling via homebrew, it is now running on the default 127.0.0.1:9042